# How to optimise run time and memory usage of code for finding the longest substring?

Tags: python, performance

I solved the question on LeetCode where you need to [find the longest substring without repeating characters](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters), but currently my code is using too much memory (~37Mb) and runs quite slowly compared to other submissions. My solution is this:

```py
class Solution:
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
        strings = [0,]
        for a in range(len(s)):
            sub = s[a]
            strings.append(len(sub))
            for char in s[a+1:]:
                if char not in sub:
                    sub += char
                else:                    
                    break                     
                strings.append(len(sub))
        return max(strings)
```

How can I improve the performance of the code? Is there a specific algorithm I should look into? Thanks!

Comment: If you're asking for better solutions to the problem, that kind of defeats the purpose? The point of the problems on leetcode is to learn to code by trying to solve the problem yourself?  However, if you're just looking for a way to measure performance, look at the standard Python library `timeit`

Comment: I'm not asking for a solution *per se*. I don't have a computer science background and so while I learned some of standard search/sort algorithms, I certainly know only a fraction of those used regularly. Therefore, I'm asking whether there's a specific standard algorithm that should be used to solve it more efficiently so that I can look it up and learn on how to use it.

Comment: Try thinking about how the code works, vs. how you would solve the problem by hand. Here's a hint. Let's say you find 150 characters at the beginning of the string and then a repeated character. Can you possibly find a longer sequence starting at the next character? Under what conditions?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, thanks for that! In the scenario you described, I'd only expect to find a longer substring if the length of the remaining string (after the duplicate) is greater than 150 characters. In that case it ends up being somewhat similar to binary search?

Comment: More to the point: could a longer substring overlap that one? Can you tell me something true about the 149-character substring starting with the second character?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, well, for starters it's shorter than the 150-character substring. But then if repeating characters were the 1st and the 150th then a substring starting at the 2nd char can be longer than 150 characters.

Comment: Exactly. I think you get to a better algorithm by following that train of thought. I didn't actually work it out myself, though :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use an algorithm called 'Sliding Window' (which is a bit like a 2-pointer algorithm). In the below solution, the 'start' variable is the pointer used.

Also, please understand the usage of hash-maps/sets/dictionaries. I have used a dictionary since you are able to lookup/search a key in O(1) Time Complexity. You are also able to insert a key in O(1) Time Complexity.

```
class Solution:
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
        if not s:
            return 0
        dic, ans, start = {}, 0, 0
        for i, v in enumerate(s):
            if v not in dic or dic[v] < start:
                ans = max(ans, i - start + 1)
            else:
                start = dic[v] + 1
            dic[v] = i
        return ans
```

This kind of questions come up quite a bit in tech interviews, so make sure you fully understand the solution I have placed above.

Comment: @Grismar, apologies for that. When writing the initial submission the Solution section is locked out (makes sense), but just like with many other features I thought it was simply locked out for non-premium users. I didn't notice that it actually becomes unlocked once you successfully submit a solution.